# Cypress login command with cy.request causes subsequent cy.visit to fail

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I'm trying to make a programmatic login with Cypress before each test. My tokens are persisted in localStorage. If I alter it synchronously, i.e. simpy doing `localStorage.setItem` without involving `cy.request` it works fine. However, I would like to use my auth server (`http://localhost:3004/login` below) to generate tokens.

The token is fetched correctly from the server, but as soon as I use the command below along with `cy.visit('/')` I get "Failed to visit localhost:8080 - We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response" (see full log below).

As far as I can tell, this is the correct approach when using an auth server for headless authentication. What did I miss?

**commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `http://localhost:3004/login`,
    body: {
      username: 'foo@bar.com',
      password: '123'
    }
  }).its('body').then((body) => {
    const vuexData = { user: { authenticationData: { token: body.token } } }
    window.localStorage.setItem('vuex', JSON.stringify(vuexData))
  })
})
```

**test.js**

```
describe('A test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.login()
  })

  it('works', () => {
    cy.visit('/')
    cy.get('h1').contains('All Books')
  })
})
```

> CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:
>
> http://localhost:8080/
>
> We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request
>   failed without a response.
>
> We received this error at the network level:
>
> > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080
>
> Common situations why this would fail:
>     - you don't have internet access
>     - you forgot to run / boot your web server
>     - your web server isn't accessible
>     - you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
>
> The stack trace for this error is:
>
> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)

Comment: Have you set the correct `baseUrl`  in cypress.json?

Comment: @JosefBiehler Yes, `http://localhost:8080`, it works fine without the `cy.request` in the login command

Comment: Failing the same thing

Comment: If I use a generic version of your code, logging vuexData within `.its('body').then((body)`, `it('works', () => {`, and the Vue app `mounted()` they all have correct values and logs occur in correct order (hitting typicode with the POST). The only thing I can suggest is to log `body` after the POST and see if it has the correct form. Elsewise, how does the Vue app use the token?

Comment: @Johan I ended up with some quick workaround so I can get over this is by getting a token from logged in test user then hard-coded it into the test. It will certain be a very bad thing to do, but it lets me get on with writing real code

Comment: Have you checked the server logs, do you see anything related to cypress requests?

Comment: Cypress has a bunch of recipe for logins, might be worth checking out https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Logging-In

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't fake logins using fixtures?

Comment: If you fake out a login using fixtures, then no interaction with an authenticated API server would work.

Comment: I have set up an example app just as you have described and Cypress works perfectly. Token is written to local storage before any call to service on 8080. Are you sure there is no problem in your app running on 8080. Replace your app with a simple index.html file with the h1 header present (or not) and try re-run the test.

Comment: Since Cypress is running at 8080 port, our actual running code which is running at 8080 is not being accessed. Tried changing the cypress port to 8081/3000, still cypress occupies 8080. That's why, outside cypress connected chrome, actual code with 8080 works properly

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a couple of mistakes here.

1. Replace `cy.route()` by [`cy.intercept()`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Comparison-to-cy-route), since the earlier one was recently deprecated and replace by the later one.
2. Check the correct syntax for using `cy.intercept()` since it's a bit different from `cy.route()`
3. I'm assuming that you're trying to bypass some sort of authentication. If all your app requires to consider a user "authenticated" is to have those information on the local storage, you don't even need to perform the POST request, but, if you do, then:
4. Check the usage of `cy.intercept()` for handling (and stubbing) the request and response objects that are related to your XHR request.
5. For setting the local storage on your Cypress window, you'll need to use the [`cy.window()`](https://example.cypress.io/commands/window#window) command.

Answer (score -2):

A couple of things.
I've never used `cypress` but any network calls are going to be async. None of your functions above are returning the promises generated from your functions. So where you create your `login` command. You need to return the promise from that function and you need to await it in your `beforeEach` function. Might be the cause of your problem, maybe not.

Is it possible you have a bug in you application where you are timing out because you have an unauthenticated request to the service running on port `8080`. Looking at the code as it stands, you are going to call `visit` (your test) before your `beforeEach` has completed. It is very likely that the data is not in local storage by the time you hit your test.

Having a quick read through the documentation on `cypress`, it looks like `cypress` tries to figure out where your service is located. The other thing which it looks like is that it appends the url defined in the `request` to the baseUrl configured. Do you actually see the auth request come in on your auth service?

Comment: Regarding async, normally you're right, but AFAIK, cypress requests run in sequence without `await`, see the example here which is similar to my case: https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Parent-Commands. Good point about the URL though, gonna check it out

Comment: See my comment above, replace your app with a simple html page and rerun that test, if it passes, it is a problem with your app not cypress.